# Bluetooth transmitter activate mobile application

Tags: c#, android, bluetooth

I'm looking for a solution to a problem. I would like to build a bluetooth transmitter that sends one simple message. For this purpose, I would like to write an application for the phone (Android, maybe iOS to), which when it is near the transmitter and receives a message, will launch, read the message and display the GUI to the user. I would rather avoid having to pair these devices (transmitter and telephone).
Are there any technologies / solutions that could be used in this type of system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like you want a BLE Beacon as your transmitter.

iBeacon is maybe the most known format of these. There are other beacon formats that are open, like [Eddystone](https://github.com/google/eddystone)

Martin Woolley from the Bluetooth SIG has done a few blogs and talks about this topic. Here is one that might be of interest [Bluetooth Beacon Applications And Real World Developers Issues](https://vimeo.com/144758130)